# Упаковка прямоугольников.

Tags: текстурный-атлас, c++, opengl

Нашел алгоритмы которые упаковывают прямоугольники, но при этом переворачивают их.

Можно ли в opengl в текстурах командой glTexSubImage2D или иной вставлять в текстуру подтекстуру переворачивая не искажая?

Если нет, то как точно называется задача, где прямоугольники не должны переворачиваться(на англ)(в идеале хотелось бы готовый код на Си/С++)?

Comment: Не уверен, но может быть можно использовать шейдеры (текстурные).

Comment: У вас задача просто получить готовый текстурный атлас? можно использовать сторонний упаковщик, или библиотеку, которая это делает.

Comment: @IronVbif  
Да такая задача. Но нужно формировать на лету.

Ну а есть готовые библиотеки?

По теме нашел:

    CRectPlacement                    - поворачивает прямоугольник.
    BinPacker(автор "scgames" gamedev)- есть bool rotated , но сам не функционирует.
    GuillotineBinPack(и еще 5 идентичных алгоритмов) (автор Jukka Jylдnki)                          - поворачивают прямоугольники.


@perfect
Ну скорее всего это можно сделать, но сам вопрос в том будет ли от этого выгода? А то ведь это может приводить к дополнительному копированию и сведет эффект от использования атласа на нет.

Comment: @manking вообще гугл много всего выдает, можно конкретно поискать по гитхабам и т.д. уж один-то точно найдется, который умеет не переворачивать.

Comment: В общем то что прямоугольники переворачиваются это даже плюс.
С помощью glTexCoord2d  и glVertex3s можно какую угодно текстуру как угодно наложить без потерь производительности.
Очень быстро и плотно укладывает библиотека MaxRectsBinPack от автора Юкка Юлднки.
Вопрос можно закрыть.

Comment: Стоит разместить это как ответ и отметить принятым.